# Hive table with Sum and group By

Tags: hive

I have one  Hive table with below data. I want to convert these 6 rows in 2 rows basesd on key and want row with type='credit'.

```
    key          type    price1
    111          null      1000
    111-21      credit    2000
    111-31      credit    3000
    222         credit    1000
    222-21      null      2000
    222-31      null      3000
```

I want to O/p as

```
    key type  price1
    111 credit 6000
    222 credit 6000
```

I have tried below query but didnt get the desired output can someone please help me how should i do this.

```
    select key,type,sum(price1) from tablename where type='credit' group by substr(key,3), type;
```

Answer (score 0):

`select key, type, sum(price1) from tablename where type = "credit" group by substr(key,1,3)`

Comment: Check if this works and if it doesn't, please share the output

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. You need to use `coalesce` to replace null values with `credit`.

```
select
    substr(key, 1, 3) as key,
    coalesce(type, 'credit') as type,
    sum(price1) as price1
from myTable
group by
    substr(key, 1, 3),
    coalesce(type, 'credit')
```